# Applying padding on td element throwing exception

Tags: javascript, css

I have declared a variable `padding`, in an alert it gives the value without problems.
However, when I use:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("td").style.height = padding;
```

I get an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'height' of undefined index.html:46
(anonymous function)`!

And that while `padding` is a correct value!!!

What then now, is wrong!?

Note: index.html:46 is the line shown above.

Comment: The clue is in the name of the method getElementsByTagName. This returns more than one element, so you have to choose which one(s) you want to alter the style of, or iterate through them all yourself.

Comment: of course `document.getElementsByTagName("td").style` is undefined

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`document.getElementsByTagName("td")` returns [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) , and it is like `Array` , so you can do:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].style.height = padding;
```

Or do it in loop:

```
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

for(var i=0 , len = tds.length; i<len; i++){
   tds[i].style.height = padding;
}
```

Comment: yes, you should loop over al table cells and give the padding, or just add a css line, this is faster.

Comment: Hmm, i have tried the loop and the error is gone for now, but the function still doesn't work. Why?

Comment: @Jaapyse what do you mean by "doesn't work" ? try to do `alert(tds.length)` , what it shows?

Comment: Well, I was typing a new message while yours appeared, the problem was in another part of the script (not shown in this question), and I've just fixed that too, so thanx, it's working!

Answer (score 1):

Its a list of nodes given by getElementsByTagName

Try:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].style.height = padding;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check if 'document.getElementsByTagName("td")' is not null.
The error message says  Cannot set property 'height' of undefined.  There is no problem with 'padding'

Comment: Agreed, have you checked "document.getElementsByTagName("td")". If you have multiple cells then this must be array and you have to loop through it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 document.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].style.height = padding;
```

The `getElementsByTagName()` method returns a collection of an elements's child elements with the specified tagname, as a NodeList object.

Answer (score 1):

two problems might be occur:

1. Your html does not contains `td` element and it returns undefined.
2. It contains `td` but multiple so you need to do indexing.

try this:

```
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
if(tds != undefined)
   tds[0].style.height = padding;
```

or

```
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
if(tds != undefined){
   for(var i=0 , len = tds.length; i<len; i++){
      tds[i].style.height = padding;
   }
}
```